# Facebook Graph API uploads photos at really bad quality

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app which automatically connects to Facebook (every 5 minutes using a cron) and updates the cover photo of a page.

Everything is working properly except for one thing: the quality of the uploaded photo is really poor. And the photo is a jpeg with the dimensions 851x315 and under 100kb.

Here is how I upload it:

```
    $response = $this->session->post('/me/photos', [
        'caption' => $caption,
        'source' => $this->session->fileToUpload($imageLocation),
        'no_story' => true
    ], $pageToken);
```

The weird part is that the API makes the image distorted, but if I generate the image and upload it manually, then it looks great on Facebook. Is there a trick? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was that I was uploading a jpg. No matter the size of the jpg (width, height or filesize) Facebook tries to manipulate it.

The solution was, in my case, to **use PNGs** instead (even if the filesize was way larger).